# What is the best way to generate HTML mail templates for the Grails mail plugin?

Tags: grails, html-email, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

With the Grails [Mail plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/mail) you can either send plain text or html mails. When sending html mails like this:

```
sendMail {
  to "fred@g2one.com"
  subject "Hello John"
  html(view: htmlTemplate, model: args)   
}
```

It is recommended to make css inline in mail html, because it will be accepted by more mail clients. The problem is, that these html files are hard to read and maintain.

Is there a way to generate these mail templates in a smarter way than writing inline css? What is a best practice to generate html mail templates?

Comment: Do you face any problem using resources plugin to evaluate your `css` in the template/gsp you would use for mail body? Have you tried using <r:require>?

Comment: When you add css as an external file some mail clients will truncate this css file. How should require help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [send an email using a template - grails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463766/send-an-email-using-a-template-grails)

Answer (score 3):

Templates can include other templates using the `g:render` tag.

If you don't want the inline css mixed with your mail html, place it in its own template and use the render tag to insert it into the html template:

mail/_css.gsp:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
      /* styles! */
    }
</style>
```

mail/_message.gsp:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <g:render template="/mail/css" /> <!-- render stylesheet into this template -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- content -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But isn't that the problem I have had? the css file will be removed from the head in some mail clients.

Comment: the render tag doesn't render a LINK to the css, it renders the CONTENT of the template into the calling template.

Comment: So you mean in produces inline css instead of a separat css file?

Comment: +1 @confile: Ideally this should be the best solution, if requiring a module attaches the css file in mail. Rendering the css as a template. Note the way the new gsp is named `_css.gsp` (template + gsp instead of `.css`)

Comment: My consideration is more that some mail clients remove the header from the mail, which contains the css.

Comment: @codelark your solution is not working in some mail clients. I have tested it and it turns out that some clients truncate the header.

Comment: Your question was how to render inline css inside an html template, and my answer covers that. If the mail clients are truncating the header, you could always render the css into the body.

Answer (score 1):

I created a gist on how to do it following a good pattern.

https://gist.github.com/biniama/7ec152189512c318c6fa

Comment: Can you post a snippet here and explain what you mean. I went to the link and couldn't find any css at all.