# rendering css with g:render from separate css file

Tags: grails

I would like to use mail plugin to send html mail. Mail client is outlook and I can't get the css file working (using: `<asset:stylesheet href="testmail.css"/>`). So I am using a css template and g:render [outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916346/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-html-mail-templates-for-the-grails-mail-plugin).... but I am getting error: "GrailsTagException: Error executing tag : null"

Any help is really appreciated. Here are my file contents:

grails-app\views\layouts\mail\_css.gsp:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        p.testp{
            margin-bottom:12.0pt;
            font-size:12.0pt;
            font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
            color:red;
        }

        .heading{
            font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
            color:#993300;
        }
    }
</style>
```

grails-app\views\test\mailtemplate.gsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Mail Template</title>

        <g:render template="/mail/css" /> 


    </head>
    <body>
       ....
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: shouldn't g:render in mailtemplate call `template="/layout/mail/css"` ?

Comment: Also, what's that `body` block in the CSS? The CSS syntax is wrong.

Comment: sebnukem: sorry, wrong copy/paste. I have following text in css.gsp and it is working fine after putting the _cc.gsp under view\mail (as pointed out by Ian).... I also need to use a layout and using <g:applyLayout name="mail/css" /> is also working fine.
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
  <style>
   
   p.passp{
    margin-bottom:12.0pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:red;
   }
   
   .redheading{
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#993300;
   }
  </style>
</head>
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<g:render template="/mail/css" />
```

will look for the template at `grails-app\views\mail\_css.gsp`, not `grails-app\views\layouts\mail\_css.gsp`.